# rails 4 delete div after remote link submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a div i want to delete after i click on a remote link. 
Currently it deletes the record in DB but I'm having trouble deleting the div after that. What is the best practice here?

Layout

```
<div><input something something ><button>destroy</button></div>
```

view.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', qa.object, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'delete-answer' %>
```

controller.rb

```
@answer.destroy
respond_to do |format|
    flash[:notice] = "Your answer has been deleted"  
  format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'questions', :action => 'edit_all' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  format.js   { render :layout => false }
end
```

destroy.js.rb (bind doesn't seem to trigger)

```
$('.delete-answer').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
    $(this).closest('div').hide();
});
```

Any ideas how i can track the button that was pressed and delete the div it is inside if destroy is successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#divToRemove").remove();
```

To track the btn, you could create a global variable - and onlcick set it to that button's ID.  Then, assuming your page doesn't allow multiple simultaneous delete answer requests, you can do something like this:

```
$("#" + btnVariable).parent("div").remove();
```

Comment: what if you do have multiple simultaneous delete answer requests? would this change?

Comment: @SurgePedroza it would have to change, although just slightly, since subsequent clicks would overwrite the variable.  You could put the delete logic in the callback event handler of the ajax call.  If this is unclear, let me know and I'll update my answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: mind helping me out here, I've started a thread..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510210/how-can-i-update-text-inside-an-alert-message-using-jquery

Comment: @SurgePedroza I could easily do what you're asking with jQuery and AJAX, but I don't use ruby on rails and am quite unfamiliar with your format in that thread, so I can't really help you.  Sorry, man.